# FORTIFY: FD_SET: file descriptor >= FD_SETSIZE error in android

Tags: java, android, webview, error-handling, chromium

I am developing a Tv app in android and my app crashes with below mentioned logcat. I gone through forums about it but didn't get any solutions to handle this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
      --------- beginning of crash
03-17 04:28:14.093 28471-28502/business A/libc: FORTIFY: FD_SET: file descriptor >= FD_SETSIZE
03-17 04:28:14.142 28471-28503/business I/System.out: current frame index=0
03-17 04:28:14.142 28471-28503/business I/System.out: current position=40549
03-17 04:28:14.229 28471-28502/business W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
03-17 04:28:14.229 28471-28502/business W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
03-17 04:28:14.229 28471-28502/business W/google-breakpad: 1.5
03-17 04:28:14.229 28471-28502/business W/google-breakpad: 6
03-17 04:28:14.229 28471-28502/business W/google-breakpad: 023f32a1-4862-425f-a49b-e5b1792614ed
03-17 04:28:14.229 28471-28502/business W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
03-17 04:28:14.229 28471-28502/business E/chromium: ### WebView Version 44.0.2403.119 (code 246011900)
03-17 04:28:14.229 28471-28502/business A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 28502 (Timer-2)
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I'm also facing same issue